# iframe size in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have *iframe* elements in my page, when the page is loaded the iframes will be re-sized and I have a button for each one to hide/show it.  After the first cycle hiding and showing it again, the size of the iframe becomes smaller and the scroll bars appear.

It only happens in Firefox and works fine in IE and Chrome, does anyone know why?

Here is some of the code:

```
function Resize_IFrame(f) {
    f.style.height = f.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

```
<body style="font-size:75%;" 
      onload="Resize_IFrame(document.getElementById('iframe1'));
              Resize_IFrame(document.getElementById('iframe2'));">

<!-- ... -->
<iframe id='iframe1' name='iframe1' width="100%" frameBorder='0' 
          src='/aa.jsp'></iframe>
<iframe id='iframe2' name='iframe2' width="100%" frameBorder='0' 
      src='/bb.jsp'></iframe>

<img src='/max.jpg'  onclick="hide('iframe1_table') ;Resize_IFrame(document.getElementById('iframe1'));"/> 

    function Hide( Table_Name )
{
    var Table      = document.getElementById( Table_Name + "_table" );
    var Hide_Icon = document.getElementById( Table_Name + "_hide_image" );
    var Add_Icon  = document.getElementById( Table_Name + "_add_image" );
    Table.style.display = 'none';
    Add_Icon.style.display  = 'block';
    Hide_Icon.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById( Table_Name + "__is_collapsed" ).value = 'Y';
}
```

Comment: Any special reason you are using IFrames here? If you'd simply include the content of the frames directly into your document, for example in a `div`, and the browser will resize that `div` for you.

Comment: Can you post the show/hide code and how this calls Resize_IFrame?

Comment: the forms are ready as a complete pages so i need to put them in IFrames , I hate to use them ,but i really stuck with them

Comment: the code for hide/show , make the display none or block for the table which contain each iframe

Comment: @ama. Ok, but you need to show all of the show/hide code, not just the call.

Comment: @ama - if you call Resize_IFrame after showing it again, doesn't it solve the problem?

Comment: Nope i tried it , you can see in the onclick event , i called the function Resize_IFrame, when i hide the table which it contains the iframe , the size of iframe become 0 and when i show it again it take a value but it is not expand according to it , it just take the default size for iframe , and scroll bars appear

Comment: Hidding the IFrame shouldn't set the size to zero - unless you are doing it in some code you are not showing. (Incidentally, you still haven't shown the whole relevant code - parts of the HTML and the code to show the IFrame are still missing). If you want a solution you'll need to show a **complete**, **working** example. It won't work if we have to worm the code bit by bit out of you.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox gives the size of the iFrame as just the visible area, so the scrollbars are excluded.

Comment: but the values of size (width and height) are approximately close before hiding and after showing, but i can distinguish that the size of it after showing not the same as before hiding by eyes ..